# Counting the number of change from one value to another value in each pandas row and sum all counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 3 possible values (1, 2, 3) as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 3], "C": [2, 3], "D": [3, 2]})
```

With this dataframe

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   2   3
2   3   3   2
```

The counts of one value to another value are

**Row 0**

```
1 -> 1 = 0   2 -> 1 = 0   3 -> 1 = 0
1 -> 2 = 0   2 -> 2 = 0   3 -> 2 = 1
1 -> 3 = 1   2 -> 3 = 1   3 -> 3 = 0
```

**Row 1**

```
1 -> 1 = 0   2 -> 1 = 0   3 -> 1 = 0
1 -> 2 = 0   2 -> 2 = 0   3 -> 2 = 1
1 -> 3 = 0   2 -> 3 = 1   3 -> 3 = 1
```

Then I sum of this counts as follow

**Total**

```
1 -> 1 = 0   2 -> 1 = 0   3 -> 1 = 0
1 -> 2 = 0   2 -> 2 = 0   3 -> 2 = 2
1 -> 3 = 1   2 -> 3 = 2   3 -> 3 = 1
```

I can think of roughly procedure as follows

Step1: transpose df

Step2: for each column of transposed df, create a temporary column by shifting 1 row of a given column

Step3: Given such a column, do groupby of such a column and a temporary column then count count

Step4: Sum of all counts

I think there might be some way more efficient than this.  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution, if you will:

1. Concatenate the original and the shifted dataframes.
2. Arrange the original and shifted values in pairs
3. Apply `tuple` to each pair
4. Count the tuples.

   ```
   pd.concat([df, df.shift(axis=1)], keys=[1,2])\
     .sort_index(level=1).dropna(axis=1).astype(int)\
     .unstack().T.apply(tuple, axis=1).value_counts()
   #(2, 3)    2
   #(3, 2)    2
   #(3, 3)    1
   #(3, 1)    1
   ```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

M1 : I am using `np.roll` here, then after combine we using `stack` and `value_counts`

```
df=df.astype(str)
df1=df.copy()
df1[:]=np.roll(df1.values,axis=1,shift=-1)
df1.iloc[:,-1]=np.NaN
(df+'->'+df1).stack().value_counts()
3->2    2
2->3    2
3->3    1
1->3    1
dtype: int64
```

---

M2 : If `roll` is hard to get it work try `shfit`

```
df = df.astype(str)
df1 = df.copy()
df1=df1.shift(-1,axis=1)
print((df + '->' + df1).stack().value_counts())
3->2    2
2->3    2
3->3    1
1->3    1
dtype: int64
```

---

M3 : Build for speed `numpy`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 3], "C": [2, 3], "D": [3, 2]})

df1 = df.copy()
df1=df1.shift(-1,axis=1)

np.unique(np.rec.fromarrays((df.values[:,:-1],df1.values[:,:-1])),return_counts=True)
(rec.array([(1, 3.), (2, 3.), (3, 2.), (3, 3.)],
          dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')]), array([1, 2, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: I have the feeling it's better to perform abstract roll on columns. Something like `new_cols = list(df.columns[1:]) + list(df.columns[:1]); df1 = df[new_cols].copy()`

Comment: @QuangHoang that is work too , also shift working here as well

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, there's a neat trick: pairs `(x,y)` with `x,y in (1,2,3)` are uniquely determined by `x*4 + y`. More specifically

```
1,1 -> 5
1,2 -> 6
1,3 -> 7
2,1 -> 9
2,2 -> 10 
2,3 -> 11
3,1 -> 13
3,2 -> 14
3,3 -> 15
```

We can use that and do

```
# compute values of these pairs across the dataset
new_df = (df[df.columns[:-1]].values * 4 + df[df.columns[1:]].values).flatten()

# count values
pd.Series(new_df).value_counts()
```

output:

```
14    2
11    2
7     1
15    1
dtype: int64
```